# No matching DOM Vendor

Tags: c++builder

I am working on a C++ application which communicates with a SOAP service. The client side has been generated in C++ Builder from the provided WSDL and it works fine on the development machine.

However on several other machines it fails with the message: No matching DOM Vendor: ""

Some searches on google point to issues with msxml libraries or the initialization there of but I haven't been able to resolve it. I also checked server traffic but the application never sends any request.

Any ideas what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the xmlrtl package to the runtime package list resolved the issue.